# Display zero filled integer on jdbc

Tags: java

How to display zero filled int value  from mysql as it is on java swing table?

As a example value in my table is 0001 but in java swing table it displays as 1.

I want to display as 0001.

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this

```
  String result= offset+rs.getString(1);
  where String offset="000";// 111 etc
```